# Emberjs - how to properly modify records on a model that has been set as a property in the controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My template:

```
    {{#each test11}}
        {{businessname}}
    {{/each}}
```

My controller that works:

```
// businessmatches is a model that is set as a controller property in the router
test11: function () {
    var raw = this.get('businessmatches');

    // I want to be able to get all the records, filter them etc etc and then
    // make them available to the template

    return [
        Ember.Object.create(raw.content.get(0)._data)
    ];
}.property('businessmatches'),
```

`raw.content.get(0)._data` feels like a hack, so I must be missing the proper way of doing this. How can I work with `businessmatches` records properly and make the new set available on the template?

**Edit**

From the router:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('businessmatches', this.store.all('businessmatch'));
}
```

The model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Businessmatch = DS.Model.extend({
    businessname: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Businessmatch;
```

Comment: what is businessMatches?  Is it an ember data record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test11: function(){
  // give me all the records that have the property foo that is 11
  var bms = this.get('businessmatches').filterBy('foo', 11);
  // give me all the records that have the property bar that is 12
  bms = bms.filterBy('bar', 12);
  // other filtering etc    
  return bms; 
  // watch foo/bar on each record, if they change, recompute this computed property
}.property('businessmatches.@each.{foo,bar,...}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756836/emberjs-how-to-set-another-property-from-computed-property-when-the-latter-is) with something I found surprising, if you 'd like to take a look.