# Emberjs - how to set another property from computed property when the latter is not on the template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

This is a follow-up from my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756465/emberjs-how-to-properly-modify-records-on-a-model-that-has-been-set-as-a-prope) question, thought it deserves a different post.

I what to set a data subset to a different property and have it available (and update-able) on the template. So I thought I 'd create an empty property and simply `set` its value.

The updated template:

```
    {{#each test12}}
        {{businessname}}
    {{/each}}
```

The controller:

```
test12: [],
test11: function(){
    var bms = this.get('businessmatches').filterBy('type', 'hardware');
    this.set('test12', bms);
    return bms;
}.property('businessmatches.@each.[type]'),
```

The problem is that this does not work. The interesting thing is that if I change the template to

```
    {{#each test12}}
        {{businessname}}
    {{/each}}
    <hr/>
    {{#each test11}}
        {{businessname}}
    {{/each}}
```

**then** it works!!! :o

I could hide the second part on a `display:none;` div or I could have the logic directly on `test12` but the behavior was a complete surprise (I thought `set` didn't work at first). Am I missing something? Is there a proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, side effects in computed properties (in your case, setting `test12`) are best avoided. They make the program hard to reason about.

In your case, the problem is that merely referring to `test12` does not compute anything. Ember has no way to know that `test12` is getting set inside `test11` and that it might need to run that. When you then refer to `test11` from the template, it is computed, with the side effect of setting `test12`, which updates the template (so fast you can't see it; to test this, you could add a `{{debugger}}` between the `test12` and `test11` parts of the template, and when you stop in the debugger, you will notice that the `test12` part is still empty).

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could do something like `test12: function() { return this.get('test11'); }.property('test11')`, or `test12: Ember.computed.alias('test11')`, which is the same thing.